# gnutls handshake failed over git clone

Tags: git, ubuntu-20.04, gnutls

When i try to clone , pull or push using git i am getting following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/***-team/****.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Access was denied
```

I tried by using 'GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1' and i got the following details:

```
16:11:00.756726 git.c:439               trace: built-in: git clone https://******S@bitbucket.org/*****-team/****.git
Cloning into '****'...
16:11:00.760746 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://******S@bitbucket.org/****-team/****.git
* Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 18.205.93.2:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to bitbucket.org (18.205.93.2) port 443 (#0)
* found 385 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Access was denied
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/INDSolv-team/icms.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Access was denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access denied due to proxy issuse, possible solution

1. Clone the repository from outside `firewall`
2. Clone the repository using `ssh` instead of `https`

### SSH

#### Step 1. Set up your default identity

1. Open Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and enter the following command to set up your default identity
   `ssh-keygen`

   Eg:

```
thirumal@thirumal:~/git$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/thirumal/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

2. Press enter to accept the default key and path, /c/Users//.ssh/id_rsa.
3. Enter and re-enter a passphrase when prompted.The command creates your default identity with its public and private keys. The whole interaction looks similar to this:

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/thirumal/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /home/thirumal/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:h4xKiyvxzOWkeXcwxmkAYSZ9AsDOikB14+vgzpTnjPs thirumal@thirumal
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|*o=o o           |
| *+ + .          |
|+  + .           |
|.o  . .o .       |
|+  ..+..S .      |
|+ .o*oB  .       |
| =.Xo= o         |
|. X.B . .        |
| ..*oE .         |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

#### Step 2 Add the public key to your Account settings

1. Copy your public key using the following command 
   `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
2. Add it to your account
3. Return to your terminal and clone the repository using ssh `git@github.com:M-Thirumal/installation_guide.git`